# Ubuntu One on WebOS device

Tags: ubuntu-one, client

What about a Ubuntu One client for WebOS?

This an awesome operating system.

Already have a Pre phone and I'll have the TouchPad.

Are you planning to release a WebOS client soon?

Comment: +1 for WebOS, though not sure if we'll see a client

Answer (score 4, accepted):

We don't have any plans to work on a WebOS client, but we'll happily support any community effort to do so, our APIs have been published: https://one.ubuntu.com/developer/

Comment: Sounds like a few new project idea

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if they are working on a WebOS client, but you could easily access your files in WebOS by simply logging in from the web interface.